# Adding multiple check box values to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, html-table

I am trying to make table that the user ticks the boxes of the food they have eaten and the carb value is sent to another table. The contents of the table are on a database where I call it with this code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
    {

    echo "<form action='add.php' method='post' id='add'><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['carb_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['food_item']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['serving_size']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['carbs_per_serving']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['carbs_per_serving']."'
 name='food[]'></td>";
         echo "</tr></form>";

                 }
        echo "<input type='submit' class='add'form='add'>";
```

The PHP for adding to the other table is:

```
<?php
        /*blog.php
            process a basic form saving data
        */

    error_reporting ('E_all');

    //Create a connection to the database
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','login') 
        or die('Error' . mysqli_error($link));

    //If there is no connection trhows up an error message
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    $food = $_POST['food'];


    //Insert values into the database       
        //mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO blog(post)
        //  VALUES ('".$post."')"
        //  );

        //echos out the information put in apart from the password
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO carbsummary(cpp)
                        VALUES ('".$food."')"
                        );
            echo $food;
    ?>
```

I hope I have explained myself properly here. In short I'm looking to have the user check the boxes then submit the carb value of the foods to the next table.

I am not that great with coding, as I've not long started, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you're trying insert an array into a query string. `$food` is an array, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

### First:

when you are creating the form, your loop will create many forms.  so you should change this code:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<form action='add.php' method='post' id='add'><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['carb_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['food_item']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['serving_size']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['carbs_per_serving']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['carbs_per_serving']."'
 name='food[]'></td>";
    echo "</tr></form>";
                 }
        echo "<input type='submit' class='add'form='add'>";
```

With this:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
        echo "<form action='add.php' method='post' id='add'>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['carb_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['food_item']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['serving_size']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['carbs_per_serving']."</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['carbs_per_serving']."'
 name='food[]'></td>";                              }
        echo "<input type='submit' class='add'form='add'>";
        echo "</tr></form>";
```

}

### Second:

$_POST['food'] contains an arrays so it will returns an array, so you should call the index for that value.

```
$food = $_POST['food'][0];
```

### Third

if you want to send many insertion at the same time you should change your form with:

```
echo "<form action='add.php' method='post' id='add'>"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){                
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['carb_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['food_item']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['serving_size']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['carbs_per_serving']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['carbs_per_serving']."'
     name='food[]'></td>";                              }
            echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "<input type='submit' class='add'form='add'></form>";
```

and then change your query execution with:

```
foreach($_POST["food"] AS $food){
     mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO carbsummary (cpp) VALUES ('{$food}')";
     echo $food;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you **must** use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for all incoming data, that goes to SQL-server.
2. You are using rather strange attribute - form="add". That's not the rude mistake, but it would be better if you remove all useless code.
3. If you want to save values to db, you need to convert array you got from client-side to string. That's not the best solution, but for the first time up you can use the `implode` function.

Change

```
$food=$_POST['food'];
```

To

```
$food=implode(',',mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['food']);
```